# Excluding a date for a recurring event in Google Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am interacting with Google Calendar using the GData library in Objective-C on iOS 5. I am able to create recurring events, however I have problems adding exceptions. Is there someone that can provide a complete, fully working code snippet showing how to use exceptions to change an occurrence details ? In addition, how do I exclude a date using an exception ? The documentation says that EXDATE clauses are honored when importing events from an external calendar file and I can confirm this. But the docs also say that the only way to modify a recurring event is through exceptions, not through the recurrence itself (trying a recurrence with EXDATE clauses indeed does not work unfortunately). So the question is: how do i reproduce the same behavior of an EXDATE clause using an exception? From what I see in the documentation, I can only modify some of the details. For instance, I can change the time of a particular occurrence, but the question is, how to exclude, instead, one or more dates ? Is this possible at all ? If not, then no application can actually sync with Google Calendar correctly and I would like to receive a confirmation about. If the answer is affirmative, please let me know how to do this. Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Objective-C remotely good enough to give you working code... but this information give you good starting point IMHO:

yes - this is possible and supported by Google Calendar... [just create a cancled event with an `originalEvent` pointing to the recurring event...](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/google-calendar-api&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/community/forum.html?place=msg%252Fgoogle-calendar-help-dataapi%252FVk6hr9-XQ3Y%252FrB1g1tlnULMJ#!msg/google-calendar-help-dataapi/Vk6hr9-XQ3Y/rB1g1tlnULMJ) another option would be [to create the recurring event directly with one or more EXDATE entries in the recurrence[] list](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/reference.html#resource_events)

An important point though:

You write you want a GData example - for Google Calendar the [GData API has been superseded](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) by the [new JSON API - for some Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/) code see for example http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/CalendarSample/EditEventWindowController.m

Comment: The first solution you provide is the correct one, checked with Google engineers. EXDATE clauses on the recurrence are ignored. However, it does not work with the Objective-C XML APIs which is broken. It may work with the new JSON based Objective-C APIs... I will try this, even though this means rewriting all of the source code interacting with Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

All I know is that Apple's own iOS Calendar doesn't seem to be able to get Google Calendar to correctly accept exceptions to recurring events, so either something is broken at the Google end or it is *hard* to do right.

Comment: You are right, the same happens when interacting programmatically with Google Calendar and this motivated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a while for what you asked for, "a complete, fully working code snippet showing how to use exceptions to change an occurrence details" and I'm sorry to say I could not find anything that responded directly to your problems, but I did find two things that MIGHT help.

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) is the first, [Here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/downloads/detail?name=CalendarHelloWorldRecurring1.0.1.zip&can=2&q=) is the second.

The first one is a class reference, and if you click on the second one is a simple add-on class for dealing with Google Calendar Recurrence specifications.

Comment: The first thing refers to the iOS calendar. I asked instead how to add exceptions to Google Calendar, but using the Google Calendar APIs. The second thing you included in your answer deals with recurrences and even includes EXDATE clauses. However, this thing is broken and never worked with exceptions. I tried this long time ago, without succeeding. It was exactly this code that led me to ask how to correctly add exceptions to Google Calendar.

Comment: Well sorry I can't help :( I looked high and low... didn't find anything else